# How to send a string from java server to C++ client?

Tags: java, c++, linux, windows, sockets

I need to send a string from a windows java server to a linux c++ client and vice versa but the code that I wrote, doesn't work and I don't know the why:

**Java server** Code on Windows **to send a string**:

```
for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++)
{
    message[i]=Byte.parseByte(num_cartella);
}                   
sendData(message,client);
```

**Java server** code on Windows **to receive data**:

```
client = server.accept();
 InputStream ic = client.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader dic = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ic) );
 String id_scelta=String.valueOf(dic.readLine());
```

**C++ client** code on Linux **to send data**:

```
if( send(sock , nCartella,(unsigned)strlen(nCartella), 0) < 0)
{
            cout <<"Invio fallito"<<endl;
            return 1;
}
cout << "Messaggio inviato"<<endl;
```

**C++ client**code on Linux **to receive data**:

```
if( recv(sock, server_reply , (unsigned)strlen(server_reply) , 0) < 0)
        {
            cout <<"Ricezione fallita"<<endl;
            return 1;
        }

        cout <<"Risposta server:";
        cout <<server_reply;
```

Why it doesn't work? the socket will create with success but client and server doesn't send and receive data and I don't know what is the wrong part of code

Comment: Are you sending and receiving in a common character encoding? Probably not. You should change the code to explicitly use UTF-8 in all 4 cases, e.g. `new InputStreamReader(ic, "UTF-8")` in the second case.

Comment: How is `nCartella` defined?  `server_reply`?  We don't know what the result of `strlen(server_reply)` is.  Also when you say "doesn't work", what does that mean exactly?  There were no runtime errors, but you didn't get the data?  There are errors, i.e., the `cout` lines in your example are showing that there is a failure?

Comment: Do you have MCVE? There can be numerous reasons. Did server accept the client and did the client bind? I would say that Java server accepts string with CRLF at the end while client sends `n` bytes of the string not necessarily ending with CRLF, so that could cause the problem too.

Comment: Case #1 in bad. Assigning `num_cartella` to *all* positions in the `message` array will not send the value of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stumbling on the same problem as thousands before you. Two of them, actually.

First problem is that when the string is sent this way, the other fellow has no idea what would be the length of the string! So you need to indicate it, and the common technique is to send string size before the actual string. When doing so, whatch out for endianness - Java is big-endian, and changes are, your other side is little-endian.

Second problem is that you can't hope to receive everything in one shot through a single `recv` command. You have to receive in a loop, until you've read all what is there.

Comment: Given `String id_scelta=String.valueOf(dic.readLine());`, I suspect that he meant to implement a line based protocol.